# Infinite loop when trying to decrement i inside a for loop

Tags: java

I have a count controlled loop for adding a series of 5 numbers inputted by the user. I have a decision structure inside it designed to reject any odd or negative numbers, but add any even positive numbers to an accumulator. To do this, I told the program to decrement i by 1 if an odd or negative number is inputted, so that the loop still accepts 5 positive even numbers. Instead, it ends up accepting an infinite number of numbers (ie. gets stuck in an infinite loop). Can someone explain why this isn't working/why it's infinite looping on me?

Here's my code:

```
public static double numberRun(){
//variable to store user input
String userNumString = "null";
int userNum = 0;
//variable to store total of all user inputted numbers
double accumulator = 0;
//setting up function to read inputs
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);   
//count for 5 loops
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
//if the total of the numbers entered so far is < 100, accept more numbers -
- doesnt affect initial number because accumulator is initialized to 0
if (accumulator < 100) {
System.out.println("Please enter a number");
//count controlled loop to ensure no more than 5 numbers are entered
 try {
  userNumString = reader.readLine();
  userNum = Integer.parseInt(userNumString);
    System.out.println(userNum);
      } catch (Exception e){
  System.out.println("Error reading from user");
}
  //reject odd or negative numbers, if a number is rejected set counter 
  back 1 to ensure 5 valid numbers total are inputted
    if (0 <= userNum) {
      if ((userNum % 2) == 0) {
        accumulator = accumulator+userNum;
      } else
        System.out.println("I'm sorry, odd numbers are not allowed");
          i=i-1;
    } else if (userNum < 0) {
         System.out.println("I'm sorry, negative numbers are not allowed");
         i=i-1;
           }
    //when the total of all user inputted numbers is ≥ 100, stop the count 
    controlled loop (stop accepting numbers)
  } else if (accumulator >= 100) {
     i=5;
  }
   }
  //return the total for the run
  return accumulator;

}
```

Comment: It will 0>= userNum and not 0 <=userNum in the if condition to check whether the number is negative or not.

Comment: I'm agree with the answer of @Thilo, you need check the contexts of IFs and ELSEs; by the way reindent your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
} else
  System.out.println("I'm sorry, odd numbers are not allowed");
  i=i-1;
```

The `i=i-1` is not part of the `else`. It is executed every time.

1. Use a code formatter
2. Always use `{}`, never bare `if` or `else` or `for` or `while`.

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I'm using Dr. Java, so it tells me what's included in my braces (not sure if that's the same as a code formatter, I'm pretty new to this). Not sure how I missed that, but I'll have to be more careful  to use {} with my else statements!
Also, i=--i will do the same thing as i=(i-1), right? I'm a bit confused on i-- vs --i, and i++ vs ++i